# Image gets rotated 90 degrees when taking portrait photo

Tags: windows, cordova, ionic2, win-universal-app, ionic3

When I'm taking an photo with my Windows Phone the landscape mode, it's perfect. The problem occurs when I'm taking a photo in portrait mode.

The photo gets rotated 90 degrees. It even occurs in the simulator as shown below.

[image][image]

Now this doesn't occur on Android or iOS so I assume this is because Windows is using the CameraProxy.js instead of/from [cordova-plugin-camera](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera).

My entire CameraProxy.js (Giant file, does contain 'rotate' stuff but method names are only about videos)

```
cordova.define("cordova-plugin-camera.CameraProxy", function(require, exports, module) {

var Camera = require('./Camera');


var getAppData = function () {
    return Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current;
};
var encodeToBase64String = function (buffer) {
    return Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.encodeToBase64String(buffer);
};
var OptUnique = Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.generateUniqueName;
var CapMSType = Windows.Media.Capture.MediaStreamType;
var webUIApp = Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication;
var fileIO = Windows.Storage.FileIO;
var pickerLocId = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId;

module.exports = {

    // args will contain :
    //  ...  it is an array, so be careful
    // 0 quality:50,
    // 1 destinationType:Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    // 2 sourceType:Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    // 3 targetWidth:-1,
    // 4 targetHeight:-1,
    // 5 encodingType:Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    // 6 mediaType:Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
    // 7 allowEdit:false,
    // 8 correctOrientation:false,
    // 9 saveToPhotoAlbum:false,
    // 10 popoverOptions:null
    // 11 cameraDirection:0

    takePicture: function (successCallback, errorCallback, args) {
        var sourceType = args[2];

        if (sourceType != Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA) {
            takePictureFromFile(successCallback, errorCallback, args);
        } else {
            takePictureFromCamera(successCallback, errorCallback, args);
        }
    }
};

// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff462087(v=vs.105).aspx
var windowsVideoContainers = [".avi", ".flv", ".asx", ".asf", ".mov", ".mp4", ".mpg", ".rm", ".srt", ".swf", ".wmv", ".vob"];
var windowsPhoneVideoContainers =  [".avi", ".3gp", ".3g2", ".wmv", ".3gp", ".3g2", ".mp4", ".m4v"];

// Default aspect ratio 1.78 (16:9 hd video standard)
var DEFAULT_ASPECT_RATIO = '1.8';

// Highest possible z-index supported across browsers. Anything used above is converted to this value.
var HIGHEST_POSSIBLE_Z_INDEX = 2147483647;

// Resize method
function resizeImage(successCallback, errorCallback, file, targetWidth, targetHeight, encodingType) {
    var tempPhotoFileName = "";
    var targetContentType = "";

    if (encodingType == Camera.EncodingType.PNG) {
        tempPhotoFileName = "camera_cordova_temp_return.png";
        targetContentType = "image/png";
    } else {
        tempPhotoFileName = "camera_cordova_temp_return.jpg";
        targetContentType = "image/jpeg";
    }

    var storageFolder = getAppData().localFolder;
    file.copyAsync(storageFolder, file.name, Windows.Storage.NameCollisionOption.replaceExisting)
        .then(function (storageFile) {
            return fileIO.readBufferAsync(storageFile);
        })
        .then(function(buffer) {
            var strBase64 = encodeToBase64String(buffer);
            var imageData = "data:" + file.contentType + ";base64," + strBase64;
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = imageData;
            image.onload = function() {
                var ratio = Math.min(targetWidth / this.width, targetHeight / this.height);
                var imageWidth = ratio * this.width;
                var imageHeight = ratio * this.height;

                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                var storageFileName;

                canvas.width = imageWidth;
                canvas.height = imageHeight;

                canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(this, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);

                var fileContent = canvas.toDataURL(targetContentType).split(',')[1];

                var storageFolder = getAppData().localFolder;

                storageFolder.createFileAsync(tempPhotoFileName, OptUnique)
                    .then(function (storagefile) {
                        var content = Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.decodeFromBase64String(fileContent);
                        storageFileName = storagefile.name;
                        return fileIO.writeBufferAsync(storagefile, content);
                    })
                    .done(function () {
                        successCallback("ms-appdata:///local/" + storageFileName);
                    }, errorCallback);
            };
        })
        .done(null, function(err) {
            errorCallback(err);
        }
    );
}

function takePictureFromFile(successCallback, errorCallback, args) {
    // Detect Windows Phone
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Windows Phone 8.1') >= 0) {
        takePictureFromFileWP(successCallback, errorCallback, args);
    } else {
        takePictureFromFileWindows(successCallback, errorCallback, args);
    }
}

function takePictureFromFileWP(successCallback, errorCallback, args) {
    var mediaType = args[6],
        destinationType = args[1],
        targetWidth = args[3],
        targetHeight = args[4],
        encodingType = args[5];

    var filePickerActivationHandler = function(eventArgs) {
        if (eventArgs.kind === Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationKind.pickFileContinuation) {
            var file = eventArgs.files[0];
            if (!file) {
                errorCallback("User didn't choose a file.");
                webUIApp.removeEventListener("activated", filePickerActivationHandler);
                return;
            }
            if (destinationType == Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI || destinationType == Camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI) {
                if (targetHeight > 0 && targetWidth > 0) {
                    resizeImage(successCallback, errorCallback, file, targetWidth, targetHeight, encodingType);
                }
                else {
                    var storageFolder = getAppData().localFolder;
                    file.copyAsync(storageFolder, file.name, Windows.Storage.NameCollisionOption.replaceExisting).done(function (storageFile) {
                        if(destinationType == Camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI) {
                            successCallback("ms-appdata:///local/" + storageFile.name);
                        }
                        else {
                            successCallback(URL.createObjectURL(storageFile));
                        }
                    }, function () {
                        errorCallback("Can't access localStorage folder.");
                    });
                }
            }
            else {
                if (targetHeight > 0 && targetWidth > 0) {
                    resizeImageBase64(successCallback, errorCallback, file, targetWidth, targetHeight);
                } else {
                    fileIO.readBufferAsync(file).done(function (buffer) {
                        var strBase64 =encodeToBase64String(buffer);
                        successCallback(strBase64);
                    }, errorCallback);
                }
            }
            webUIApp.removeEventListener("activated", filePickerActivationHandler);
        }
    };

    var fileOpenPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
    if (mediaType == Camera.MediaType.PICTURE) {
        fileOpenPicker.fileTypeFilter.replaceAll([".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg"]);
        fileOpenPicker.suggestedStartLocation = pickerLocId.picturesLibrary;
    }
    else if (mediaType == Camera.MediaType.VIDEO) {
        fileOpenPicker.fileTypeFilter.replaceAll(windowsPhoneVideoContainers);
        fileOpenPicker.suggestedStartLocation = pickerLocId.videosLibrary;
    }
    else {
        fileOpenPicker.fileTypeFilter.replaceAll(["*"]);
        fileOpenPicker.suggestedStartLocation = pickerLocId.documentsLibrary;
    }

    webUIApp.addEventListener("activated", filePickerActivationHandler);
    fileOpenPicker.pickSingleFileAndContinue();
}

function takePictureFromFileWindows(successCallback, errorCallback, args) {
    var mediaType = args[6],
        destinationType = args[1],
        targetWidth = args[3],
        targetHeight = args[4],
        encodingType = args[5];

    var fileOpenPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
    if (mediaType == Camera.MediaType.PICTURE) {
        fileOpenPicker.fileTypeFilter.replaceAll([".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg"]);
        fileOpenPicker.suggestedStartLocation = pickerLocId.picturesLibrary;
    }
    else if (mediaType == Camera.MediaType.VIDEO) {
        fileOpenPicker.fileTypeFilter.replaceAll(windowsVideoContainers);
        fileOpenPicker.suggestedStartLocation = pickerLocId.videosLibrary;
    }
    else {
        fileOpenPicker.fileTypeFilter.replaceAll(["*"]);
        fileOpenPicker.suggestedStartLocation = pickerLocId.documentsLibrary;
    }

    fileOpenPicker.pickSingleFileAsync().done(function (file) {
        if (!file) {
            errorCallback("User didn't choose a file.");
            return;
        }
        if (destinationType == Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI || destinationType == Camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI) {
            if (targetHeight > 0 && targetWidth > 0) {
                resizeImage(successCallback, errorCallback, file, targetWidth, targetHeight, encodingType);
            }
            else {
                var storageFolder = getAppData().localFolder;
                file.copyAsync(storageFolder, file.name, Windows.Storage.NameCollisionOption.replaceExisting).done(function (storageFile) {
                        if(destinationType == Camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI) {
                            successCallback("ms-appdata:///local/" + storageFile.name);
                        }
                        else {
                            successCallback(URL.createObjectURL(storageFile));
                        }
                }, function () {
                    errorCallback("Can't access localStorage folder.");
                });
            }
        }
        else {
            if (targetHeight > 0 && targetWidth > 0) {
                resizeImageBase64(successCallback, errorCallback, file, targetWidth, targetHeight);
            } else {
                fileIO.readBufferAsync(file).done(function (buffer) {
                    var strBase64 =encodeToBase64String(buffer);
                    successCallback(strBase64);
                }, errorCallback);
            }
        }
    }, function () {
        errorCallback("User didn't choose a file.");
    });
}

function takePictureFromCamera(successCallback, errorCallback, args) {
    // Check if necessary API available
    if (!Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI) {
        takePictureFromCameraWP(successCallback, errorCallback, args);
    } else {
        takePictureFromCameraWindows(successCallback, errorCallback, args);
    }
}

function takePictureFromCameraWP(successCallback, errorCallback, args) {
    // We are running on WP8.1 which lacks CameraCaptureUI class
    // so we need to use MediaCapture class instead and implement custom UI for camera
    var destinationType = args[1],
        targetWidth = args[3],
        targetHeight = args[4],
        encodingType = args[5],
        saveToPhotoAlbum = args[9],
        cameraDirection = args[11],
        capturePreview = null,
        cameraCaptureButton = null,
        cameraCancelButton = null,
        capture = null,
        captureSettings = null,
        CaptureNS = Windows.Media.Capture,
        sensor = null;
    }


    function continueVideoOnFocus() {
        // if preview is defined it would be stuck, play it
        if (capturePreview) {
            capturePreview.play();
        }
    }

    function startCameraPreview() {
        // Search for available camera devices
        // This is necessary to detect which camera (front or back) we should use
        var DeviceEnum = Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
        var expectedPanel = cameraDirection === 1 ? DeviceEnum.Panel.front : DeviceEnum.Panel.back;

        // Add focus event handler to capture the event when user suspends the app and comes back while the preview is on
        window.addEventListener("focus", continueVideoOnFocus);

        DeviceEnum.DeviceInformation.findAllAsync(DeviceEnum.DeviceClass.videoCapture).then(function (devices) {
            if (devices.length <= 0) {
                destroyCameraPreview();
                errorCallback('Camera not found');
                return;
            }

            devices.forEach(function(currDev) {
                if (currDev.enclosureLocation.panel && currDev.enclosureLocation.panel == expectedPanel) {
                    captureSettings.videoDeviceId = currDev.id;
                }
            });

            captureSettings.photoCaptureSource = Windows.Media.Capture.PhotoCaptureSource.photo;

            return capture.initializeAsync(captureSettings);
        }).then(function () {

            // create focus control if available
            var VideoDeviceController = capture.videoDeviceController;
            var FocusControl = VideoDeviceController.focusControl;

            if (FocusControl.supported === true) {
                capturePreview.addEventListener('click', function () {
                    // Make sure function isn't called again before previous focus is completed
                    if (this.getAttribute('clicked') === '1') {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        this.setAttribute('clicked', '1');
                    }
                    var preset = Windows.Media.Devices.FocusPreset.autoNormal;
                    var parent = this;
                    FocusControl.setPresetAsync(preset).done(function () {
                        // set the clicked attribute back to '0' to allow focus again
                        parent.setAttribute('clicked', '0');
                    });
                });
            }

            // msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452807.aspx
            capturePreview.msZoom = true;
            capturePreview.src = URL.createObjectURL(capture);
            capturePreview.play();

            // Bind events to controls
            sensor = Windows.Devices.Sensors.SimpleOrientationSensor.getDefault();
            if (sensor !== null) {
                sensor.addEventListener("orientationchanged", onOrientationChange);
            }

            // add click events to capture and cancel buttons
            cameraCaptureButton.addEventListener('click', onCameraCaptureButtonClick);
            cameraCancelButton.addEventListener('click', onCameraCancelButtonClick);

            // Change default orientation
            if (sensor) {
                setPreviewRotation(sensor.getCurrentOrientation());
            } else {
                setPreviewRotation(Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.getForCurrentView().currentOrientation);
            }

            // Get available aspect ratios
            var aspectRatios = getAspectRatios(capture);

            // Couldn't find a good ratio
            if (aspectRatios.length === 0) {
                destroyCameraPreview();
                errorCallback('There\'s not a good aspect ratio available');
                return;
            }

            // add elements to body
            document.body.appendChild(capturePreview);
            document.body.appendChild(cameraCaptureButton);
            document.body.appendChild(cameraCancelButton);

            if (aspectRatios.indexOf(DEFAULT_ASPECT_RATIO) > -1) {
                return setAspectRatio(capture, DEFAULT_ASPECT_RATIO);
            } else {
                // Doesn't support 16:9 - pick next best
                return setAspectRatio(capture, aspectRatios[0]);
            }
        }).done(null, function (err) {
            destroyCameraPreview();
            errorCallback('Camera intitialization error ' + err);
        });
    }

    function destroyCameraPreview() {
        // If sensor is available, remove event listener
        if (sensor !== null) {
            sensor.removeEventListener('orientationchanged', onOrientationChange);
        }

        // Pause and dispose preview element
        capturePreview.pause();
        capturePreview.src = null;

        // Remove event listeners from buttons
        cameraCaptureButton.removeEventListener('click', onCameraCaptureButtonClick);
        cameraCancelButton.removeEventListener('click', onCameraCancelButtonClick);

        // Remove the focus event handler
        window.removeEventListener("focus", continueVideoOnFocus);

        // Remove elements
        [capturePreview, cameraCaptureButton, cameraCancelButton].forEach(function (elem) {
            if (elem /* && elem in document.body.childNodes */) {
                document.body.removeChild(elem);
            }
        });

        // Stop and dispose media capture manager
        if (capture) {
            capture.stopRecordAsync();
            capture = null;
        }
    }

    function getAspectRatios(capture) {
        var videoDeviceController = capture.videoDeviceController;
        var photoAspectRatios = videoDeviceController.getAvailableMediaStreamProperties(CapMSType.photo).map(function (element) {
            return (element.width / element.height).toFixed(1);
        }).filter(function (element, index, array) { return (index === array.indexOf(element)); });

        var videoAspectRatios = videoDeviceController.getAvailableMediaStreamProperties(CapMSType.videoRecord).map(function (element) {
            return (element.width / element.height).toFixed(1);
        }).filter(function (element, index, array) { return (index === array.indexOf(element)); });

        var videoPreviewAspectRatios = videoDeviceController.getAvailableMediaStreamProperties(CapMSType.videoPreview).map(function (element) {
            return (element.width / element.height).toFixed(1);
        }).filter(function (element, index, array) { return (index === array.indexOf(element)); });

        var allAspectRatios = [].concat(photoAspectRatios, videoAspectRatios, videoPreviewAspectRatios);

        var aspectObj = allAspectRatios.reduce(function (map, item) {
            if (!map[item]) {
                map[item] = 0;
            }
            map[item]++;
            return map;
        }, {});

        return Object.keys(aspectObj).filter(function (k) {
            return aspectObj[k] === 3;
        });
    }

    function setAspectRatio(capture, aspect) {
        // Max photo resolution with desired aspect ratio
        var videoDeviceController = capture.videoDeviceController;
        var photoResolution = videoDeviceController.getAvailableMediaStreamProperties(CapMSType.photo)
            .filter(function (elem) {
                return ((elem.width / elem.height).toFixed(1) === aspect);
            })
            .reduce(function (prop1, prop2) {
                return (prop1.width * prop1.height) > (prop2.width * prop2.height) ? prop1 : prop2;
            });

        // Max video resolution with desired aspect ratio
        var videoRecordResolution = videoDeviceController.getAvailableMediaStreamProperties(CapMSType.videoRecord)
            .filter(function (elem) {
                return ((elem.width / elem.height).toFixed(1) === aspect);
            })
            .reduce(function (prop1, prop2) {
                return (prop1.width * prop1.height) > (prop2.width * prop2.height) ? prop1 : prop2;
            });

        // Max video preview resolution with desired aspect ratio
        var videoPreviewResolution = videoDeviceController.getAvailableMediaStreamProperties(CapMSType.videoPreview)
            .filter(function (elem) {
                return ((elem.width / elem.height).toFixed(1) === aspect);
            })
            .reduce(function (prop1, prop2) {
                return (prop1.width * prop1.height) > (prop2.width * prop2.height) ? prop1 : prop2;
            });

        return videoDeviceController.setMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(CapMSType.photo, photoResolution)
            .then(function () {
                return videoDeviceController.setMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(CapMSType.videoPreview, videoPreviewResolution);
            })
            .then(function () {
                return videoDeviceController.setMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(CapMSType.videoRecord, videoRecordResolution);
            });
    }


    /**
     * When the phone orientation change, get the event and change camera preview rotation
     * @param  {Object} e - SimpleOrientationSensorOrientationChangedEventArgs
     */
    function onOrientationChange(e) {
        setPreviewRotation(e.orientation);
    }

    /**
     * Converts SimpleOrientation to a VideoRotation to remove difference between camera sensor orientation
     * and video orientation
     * @param  {number} orientation - Windows.Devices.Sensors.SimpleOrientation
     * @return {number} - Windows.Media.Capture.VideoRotation
     */
    function orientationToRotation(orientation) {
        // VideoRotation enumerable and BitmapRotation enumerable have the same values
        // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.videorotation.aspx
        // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmaprotation.aspx

        switch (orientation) {
            // portrait
            case Windows.Devices.Sensors.SimpleOrientation.notRotated:
                return Windows.Media.Capture.VideoRotation.clockwise90Degrees;
            // landscape
            case Windows.Devices.Sensors.SimpleOrientation.rotated90DegreesCounterclockwise:
                return Windows.Media.Capture.VideoRotation.none;
            // portrait-flipped (not supported by WinPhone Apps)
            case Windows.Devices.Sensors.SimpleOrientation.rotated180DegreesCounterclockwise:
                // Falling back to portrait default
                return Windows.Media.Capture.VideoRotation.clockwise90Degrees;
            // landscape-flipped
            case Windows.Devices.Sensors.SimpleOrientation.rotated270DegreesCounterclockwise:
                return Windows.Media.Capture.VideoRotation.clockwise180Degrees;
            // faceup & facedown
            default:
                // Falling back to portrait default
                return Windows.Media.Capture.VideoRotation.clockwise90Degrees;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Rotates the current MediaCapture's video
     * @param {number} orientation - Windows.Devices.Sensors.SimpleOrientation
     */
    function setPreviewRotation(orientation) {
        capture.setPreviewRotation(orientationToRotation(orientation));
    }

    try {
        createCameraUI();
        startCameraPreview();
    } catch (ex) {
        errorCallback(ex);
    }
}

function takePictureFromCameraWindows(successCallback, errorCallback, args) {
    var destinationType = args[1],
        targetWidth = args[3],
        targetHeight = args[4],
        encodingType = args[5],
        allowCrop = !!args[7],
        saveToPhotoAlbum = args[9],
        WMCapture = Windows.Media.Capture,
        cameraCaptureUI = new WMCapture.CameraCaptureUI();

    cameraCaptureUI.photoSettings.allowCropping = allowCrop;

    if (encodingType == Camera.EncodingType.PNG) {
        cameraCaptureUI.photoSettings.format = WMCapture.CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.png;
    } else {
        cameraCaptureUI.photoSettings.format = WMCapture.CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.jpeg;
    }

    // decide which max pixels should be supported by targetWidth or targetHeight.
    var maxRes = null;
    var UIMaxRes = WMCapture.CameraCaptureUIMaxPhotoResolution;
    var totalPixels = targetWidth * targetHeight;

    if (targetWidth == -1 && targetHeight == -1) {
        maxRes = UIMaxRes.highestAvailable;
    }
    // Temp fix for CB-10539
    /*else if (totalPixels <= 320 * 240) {
        maxRes = UIMaxRes.verySmallQvga;
    }*/
    else if (totalPixels <= 640 * 480) {
        maxRes = UIMaxRes.smallVga;
    } else if (totalPixels <= 1024 * 768) {
        maxRes = UIMaxRes.mediumXga;
    } else if (totalPixels <= 3 * 1000 * 1000) {
        maxRes = UIMaxRes.large3M;
    } else if (totalPixels <= 5 * 1000 * 1000) {
        maxRes = UIMaxRes.veryLarge5M;
    } else {
        maxRes = UIMaxRes.highestAvailable;
    }

    cameraCaptureUI.photoSettings.maxResolution = maxRes;

    var cameraPicture;

    // define focus handler for windows phone 10.0
    var savePhotoOnFocus = function () {
        window.removeEventListener("focus", savePhotoOnFocus);
        // call only when the app is in focus again
        savePhoto(cameraPicture, {
            destinationType: destinationType,
            targetHeight: targetHeight,
            targetWidth: targetWidth,
            encodingType: encodingType,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: saveToPhotoAlbum
        }, successCallback, errorCallback);
    };

    cameraCaptureUI.captureFileAsync(WMCapture.CameraCaptureUIMode.photo).done(function (picture) {
        if (!picture) {
            errorCallback("User didn't capture a photo.");
            // Remove the focus handler if present
            window.removeEventListener("focus", savePhotoOnFocus);
            return;
        }
        cameraPicture = picture;

        // If not windows 10, call savePhoto() now. If windows 10, wait for the app to be in focus again
        if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Windows Phone 10.0') < 0) {
            savePhoto(cameraPicture, {
                destinationType: destinationType,
                targetHeight: targetHeight,
                targetWidth: targetWidth,
                encodingType: encodingType,
                saveToPhotoAlbum: saveToPhotoAlbum
            }, successCallback, errorCallback);
        }
    }, function () {
        errorCallback("Fail to capture a photo.");
        window.removeEventListener("focus", savePhotoOnFocus);
    });
}

require("cordova/exec/proxy").add("Camera",module.exports);

});
```

Does anyone know how I can keep my image rotation in Windows?

Comment: Last comment on this link - https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/issues/297 shows that its an open issue for now

Comment: sorry, that link was of a different plugin. open issue - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11217

Answer (score 2):

In your CameraProxy.js make changes in orientationToRotation function line number `569`.

```
case Windows.Devices.Sensors.SimpleOrientation.notRotated:
            if (cameraDirection == 0) {
                return Windows.Media.Capture.VideoRotation.clockwise90Degrees;
            }
            else {
                return Windows.Media.Capture.VideoRotation.clockwise270Degrees;
            }
```

For More Info you can refer this [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33731152/cordova-windows-phone-app-camera-orientation-is-wrong)

Comment: @ivaro i'm assuming you are using the Latest version of the plugin?

Comment: @ivaro and from the  first image i can see that  even though u have taken pic in `portrait` mode but the `camera` setting are in `landscape` mode